# Error accessing Google Drive in open wifi

Tags: wireless-networking, certificate, safari, google-drive

I'm trying to use Google Drive (https://drive.google.com) but safari keep saying:

```
"Safari can't open the page https://drive.google.com because Safari     
can't establish a secure connection to the server drive.google.com"
```

If I try with other browser, the same happens:

```
"This site cannot be loaded due to a certificate error: 
https://drive.google.com/ net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID"
```

Trying different things to fix it, I discovered that if I share internet from my phone, I can access it without problems. So I guess the problem has something to do with the open wifi network I'm using (at my library).

Any idea what is happening and why? It is possible to fix it?

Comment: Only drive is opening ? Can you able to access gmail and google search.

Comment: gmail, google search and any other website I'm visiting work perfectly, is just with Drive

Comment: What sort of environment is this in?  At work I can access Google Mail without a problem, but the proxy, would block a connection to Google Drive.  Google takes extra steps to detect clients using invalid certificates.